# Connect points by line in matlab 3D scatter plot according to index number

Tags: matlab, 3d, visualization, scatter-plot

I need to connect points by line in matlab 3D scatter plot according to index number. So far I got to this state

```
data = importdata('2.txt');
x = data (:,1);
y = data (:,2);
z = data (:,3);
MarkerSize = 50;
SizeVector = repmat(MarkerSize ,length(x),1);
ColorVector = summer(length(x));
h = scatter3(x,y,z,SizeVector,ColorVector,'filled');
view(-30,10)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpIdK.png)

P.S.
This program is new for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I get the question. Isn't `line` what you're looking for?

```
x=[1 2 3];%let's say
y=[1 3 2];
z=[1 2 3];

figure;hold on
plot3(x,y,z)
line(x,y,z)%this links the dots in the order specified in when defining x,y and z
```